# Can i compose a multisig address where one of the signatories is a multisig address?

Tags: multi-signature, musig

Can i compose a multisig address where one of the signatories is a multisig address?
In order to create a multisig address we need the pubkey of the signatories.

```
bitcoin­cli addmultisigaddress 2 
'["pubkey1", "pubkey2",..."pubkey(n)"]'
```

Is anything stopping me from using a multisig address as one of the signatories?

Essentially: can one of the signatories be a multisig address (one that currently starts with a 3).

Answer (score 1):

No this is not supported behavior. You can manually add the public keys from one multisig script into another, but a multisignature script can not be nested within another.

Comment: It was always supported by Bitcoin Script, and there is now tools to be able to use that safely (output descriptors with Miniscript support).

Comment: @AntoinePoinsot: I think the question asker is asking about the equivalent of a nested MuSig2 key within a script? If he is then that wasn't possible until Schnorr (or at least an equivalent MuSig2 scheme wasn't specified for ECDSA)

Comment: I don't think he's asking about a public key aggregation scheme specifically, just about having the feature "a 2-of-3 where one of the signer is actually a 2-of-3 (or another sort of multisig)". And it's precisely one of the things Miniscript makes possible: composability. Also, you wouldn't be able to have a threshold with Musig2 directly (only by using a Taproot tree) and he's using a 2-of-3 in his question. TL;DR: both work. You can either use Miniscript or have aggregated keys in separate Taproot leaves, but i'd argue the latter is significantly more involved at the moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Update to Claris' answer in April 2023:

With Schnorr signatures (enabled in the Taproot soft fork that activated in November 2021) you can now generate a single Schnorr public key that is the aggregate of multiple other valid Schnorr public keys and create a single aggregated signature from them. This aggregated Schnorr public key can be nested within another multisig scheme. However, your Bitcoin address needs to be a Taproot address (SegWit v1) starting `bc1p....` rather than `3....`